Problems with load order for JavaScript Modules
Github repo: https://github.com/leighhobson89/ChipshopChopper
I am having difficulties in forcing one .js file to run its code before another one attempts to.  The grit of the problem is that I am calling a function via a dispatch event in one file (lets call it 1.js), and the function it calls is in the second file (lets call it 2.js).  However, even though it does call the function when the event dispatch triggers, the variable it is supposed to write to in that function is returning not defined (it is declared above the function in 2.js)
I have tried declaring this variable in 1.js before dispatching the event, and exporting it, but then I get the error saying you cannot assign to a constant variable.  The whole point of this exercise is to have this constant in its own file because it is a big long list of DOM elements, and I dont want to have to keep calling document.getElementById() every time I want to affect the innerHTML  of an element, so I created an event to trigger to call this function at a point in the code I want it to load it, i.e. after the elements are created but before they are requested to be changed.
I'd like a way, other than defer or sorting the order in the HTML, or putting the script in the <head> tag, all of which I have tried without success, to force it to initialize the variable in 2.js before doing anything in 1.js.
I will provide code samples if anyone wants to see them, but it is difficult to get a context without pasting vast swathes of code from multiple files, so apologies in advance for that.
From research online I tried:

defer to try and make 1.js load before 2.js
putting 1.js in the <head> tag
creating a Promise in the function that sets the elements variable, to resolve when elements has a value other than null or undefined (but I dont have a good command of async programming so it was maybe right or not)
swapping out the order of the <script> tags in the HTML file.

1.js:
let elements;

export function setElements() {
      elements = {
        option1: document.getElementById('option1'),
        option2: document.getElementById('option2'),
        //etc
      }

2.js
import {getElements, setElements} from './1.js'

document.addEventListener('titleScreenCreated', setElements);
const titleScreenCreatedEvent = new Event('titleScreenCreated');
createGameWindow(titleScreenCreatedEvent);
//code that creates various elements
document.dispatchEvent(titleScreenCreatedEvent);
console.log(getElements());
//code that changes elements
// getElements().option1.innerHTML = "hello world";

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Your Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="clock">00:00:00</div>
<script type="module" src="actions.js"></script>
<script defer type="module" src="1.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="ui.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


Difficult to understand your problem without seeing a simplified code example.

@Yousaf I added some simplified samples and the whole index.html file

The way it is set up now it will never be filled in correctly, as all your modules only share if they come from the same module root. So if you import both in a unified import file, it might start working. Right now importing 1.js using the script tag which loads in 2.js will be a seperate instance from 2.js loaded using a script tag.

Hi Leigh, welcome to StackOverflow! I don't think the problem is where you assume it is. I have run your code (after a few syntax fixes), and it prints the elements in getElements just as expected. Unfortunately, you will have to dive deep into that "vast swathes of code" with a debugger to figure out what is going wrong. I suggest you put breakpoints into the setter and the getter as a first step, to verify the execution order.

@somethinghere It loaded only once when I tested in Chrome

@somethinghere thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately I was unable to understand the full extent of what you were alluding to.  Could you possibly write a line or two of pseudo code that would just give me an idea on how i should change the import structure, and in which files to do this?

@TamasHegedus thanks for your reply.  You may be right, but most of the code not included is just creating elements.  The error indicates that in this order, the elements variable cannot be accessed before initialization.  And as it is declared, I can only assume (and also fortified by break points to see execution order) it is accessing the setElements() function via the event, before reading in any of the stuff in the 1.js file (which incidentally is a constantsAndGlobalVars.js file where i keep all my constants and getter/setter methods.)

I have added a link to the github repo to the post as it is exactly now if anyone has the time to run it, just to see.  https://github.com/leighhobson89/ChipshopChopper

You should first remove your cycles. Circular dependencies should be avoided.

@somethinghere Why do you think so? I tested it, and Chrome does not seem to create parallel module graphs, it seems to resolve them into one big graph where each module is initialized only once, just as I would expect.

That's weird, I was sure this was the case before. Just tested it and it indeed does it differently than I was used too. Good to know, but kind of weird as I swear I ran into this kind of issue of before because of it. Ah well.

Thanks for linking the GitHub repository, this way I was able to reproduce your problem.
Your game tries to create the UI when the modules are not fully loaded yet. I suggest creating a main function to serve as the entry point for your application and moving every bit of game initialization into that function. Make sure to call it after all modules are initialized, for example, use the DOMContentLoaded event.
function main() {
  document.addEventListener('titleScreenCreated', settlements);
  const titleScreenCreatedEvent = new Event('titleScreenCreated');
  createGameWindow(titleScreenCreatedEvent);
  createTitleScreen();

  gameLoop();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  main();
});

On a more general note, you only see this kind of problem when there are dependency cycles around. When this happens, there is no reliable way to control the loading order, you have to restructure the application. The best way around it is to avoid cycles altogether, if possible.

Problem solved and a good lesson learnt!  Excellent, thanks for your help!
